# Configure child router to compose modules in parent router viewport html binding

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

**Objective:**
I want the segregation and encapsulation benefits of utilizing child routers to organize routes by significant feature areas of the app. However, I want to have those routes handled and composed by the parent router viewport binding. i.e

`<div id="parentRouterViewport" data-bind="router: { cacheViews: true }"><div>`

So far, everything I have tried including making calls back to the parent router to delegate the route (as an experiment) have failed. Making me wonder if this is even possible.

*For brevity, I'm just including the mission critcal code sections for the routing.*

**shell.js**

```
return {
        router: router,
        activate: function() {
            return router.map([
                    { route: 'App*splat', moduleId: 'app/home/viewmodels/index', title: 'Home', nav: true }
                ]).buildNavigationModel()
                .mapUnknownRoutes('app/home/viewmodels/error')
                .activate();
        }
    };
```

**shell.html**

```
<div id="content" data-bind="router: { cacheViews: true }"></div>
```

**index.js (child routing module)**

```
var childRouter = router.createChildRouter()
        .makeRelative({
            moduleId: 'app/home/viewmodels',
            fromParent: true
        }).map([
            { route: 'EligibiltySearch',    moduleId: 'eligibilitySearch',  title: 'Eligibility Search',    nav: true }
        ]).buildNavigationModel();

    return {
        router: childRouter
    };
});
```

The only way this works is if I place a router viewport binding in my corresponding *index.html* view. However, this is not what I am after based on the css layout and page look and feel I am trying to design. Everything should be represented as a panel and swapped out for a different panel whenever a route is hit. Currently, this approach will have two panels constantly open. Take a look at the photo below for better context on what I mean.

[image: Photo of the CSS layout issue described above]

Comment: Are you trying to achieve something similar to this [Durandal Example](http://dfiddle.github.io/dFiddle-2.0/#view-composition)?

Answer (score 3):

In our team, we have created our own "child routers" using Knockout variables to show/hide the subViews based on tab button click. One caveat with this is that you will have to call your activate, deactivate, compositionComplete, etc from the main/parent view to get the subView to work. There are some other gotchas, but I figured I'd give you this as an option or others who see this question later.